# In Azure AD associate IDP Identity to existing users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, idp

I've connected an Azure AD to a OpenId IDP (based on KeyCloak) using Azure AD B2C. The connections works well and user can use external IDP to create an user on Azure AD an login in an basic application that I use for test.

I would like to connect existing user in Azure AD to the relative IDP identity.

Using Graph API, in users detail I've notice that users created from IDP has in identities array an identity with `"signInType": "federated"`.

In [Update user graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) seams that `identities` isn't an updatable value.

Is it possible to connect the user on Azure to my external IDP?

Answer (score 0):

•   You want to connect the user ID in Azure to the external IDP, i.e., you want the user in Azure AD to login with Azure AD credentials in external/other IDP. Thus, you will want to federate your Azure AD tenant with the external IDP for Azure AD to be provisioned in external IDP and use SAML SSO for authentication purposes.

For the sake of convenience, let’s assume here that external IDP is Google cloud. So, you want to connect your Azure AD users to the Google cloud IDP, for this purpose, you would want to configure a federation between Google cloud Identity and Azure AD such that Azure AD users are provisioned in Google cloud workspace and these users use SAML SSO for authentication in Google cloud using their Azure AD provisioned identities. To configure the same, please refer the below documentation link for that purpose: -

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-active-directory